# SAS Newcomer: Data arrangement for a ProcFreq

Tags: database, sas

Looking at running a ProcFreq on the following snippet of data

[SampleData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FCSi.png)

Looking to find out the proportion of MutYes to MutNo by gene, comparing/controlling cancer.
Here's the code that I've got so far:

```
Proc Freq data=polysorted;
by Gene;
weight Status;
table MutYes*MutNo /chisq ;
run;
```

My question is how do I need to rearrange the data to make this work correctly. Right now, it's giving me:

ERROR: Variable Status in list does not match type prescribed for this list.

Trying to get a layout like this:

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGgOw.jpg)

clearly outlying the proportion of MutYes to MutNo by control and cancer for each gene

Comment: Hi!  Please add data as text in your question, as opposed to pictures; see how data_null included "cards" in his response below, for example.  In general, images don't belong in questions here unless you're asking a graphing question, as they make it harder to answer your question properly.  Thanks!

Comment: Having `weight status;` is the issue, it needs to be a numeric variable, you cannot weight by categories.

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable(resp) with value Y/N and WEIGHT variable(Y) for the counts;

```
data mut;
   do gene = 'ATPhase6','ATPhase8';
      do status = 'Control','PC';
         do resp = 'Yes','No';
            input Y @;
            output;
            end;
         end;
      end;
   cards;
29 236
21 169
 6 259
13 177
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc freq data=mut order=data;
   by gene;
   table status*resp / cmh;
   weight y;
   run;
```

Comment: My apologies my original question was not worded as well as it should have been. I have a lot of genes to look at and don't want to retype them all into cards. Is there a way to do it with my dataset and a Proc Freq?

Comment: @DanielJennings Yes you can use your data but you will need to modify the structure slightly.  If you post some of you data as TEXT I will write the code to transpose the data.

Comment: Method Control- Mutation Control- No Mutation Cancer- Mutation Cancer- No Mutation /
ATPase6 PolyPhen 29 236 21 169/
ATPase8 PolyPhen 6 259 13 177/
ND1 PolyPhen 1 264 2 188/
ND2 PolyPhen 3 262 3 187/
ND3 PolyPhen 5 260 3 187/
ND4 PolyPhen 5 260 7 183/
ND4L PolyPhen 0 265 0 190/
ND5 PolyPhen 23 242 31 159/